# Person counting for a store using image processing techniques in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am new to image processing and am writing a small application in which I need to count the number of people entering a store. The entry point is fixed and there are 4 camera feeds in the same video to do the same counting. What can I possibly use to do this?

I have used Running Average and Background subtraction till now and that has given me only parts of the image which involve a person. How do I use this for counting? I am using OpenCV with C++.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use the haar cascades to identify people and then add. Its a very crude way to get it done and might need some pre-processing.

Comment: Pre-processing like Thresholding or conversion to grayscale? Things like that?

Comment: Hi, as you said you are developing a simple application, you can use virtual trip wire, may be this can be useful demo link http://www.i2vsys.com/products.html?id=3&aid=30-51&subid=3-7 ... If u really want to use four cameras and acurate detection under uncontrolled environment this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have at your disposal multiple video stream you can calibrate your system to create a passive stereo framework.

I've already seen many work on this topic like this one:
http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~iocchi/publications/iocchi-ie05.pdf

You can also take a look at this question:
[People counting using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560726/people-counting-using-opencv)